# Snap NodeJS pugin returns error: Command '['/bin/sh', '/tmp/tmp4fqy7jgb', 'npm', '--cache-min=Infinity', 'install']' returned non-zero exit status 2

Tags: node.js, npm, coffeescript, snapcraft

I'm trying to snap YakYak, the popular cross-platform Google Hangouts client, because the devs haven't bothered to package it and I thought it could benefit from having a Snap. Because it's mostly written in CoffeeScript/NodeJS,I thought it had better use the NodeJS Snapcraft plugin. But for some reason, whenever I try to run `snapcraft prime`, as per step 4 in the [Ubuntu Tutorials tutorial,](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/create-your-first-snap#3), it outputs the following:

```
Preparing to pull yakyak 
Pulling yakyak 

Cloning into '/home/sam/Documents/Code/Active Projects/parts/yakyak/src'...
remote: Counting objects: 8261, done.
remote: Total 8261 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 8260
Receiving objects: 100% (8261/8261), 12.41 MiB | 2.26 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (6249/6249), done.
Downloading 'node-v6.10.2-linux-x64.tar.gz'[==============================] 100%
npm --cache-min=Infinity install
/tmp/tmp4fqy7jgb: 3: export: Projects/stage/usr/share/perl5/: bad variable name
Command '['/bin/sh', '/tmp/tmp4fqy7jgb', 'npm', '--cache-min=Infinity', 'install']' returned non-zero exit status 2
```

I have both NodeJS and NPM on my computer. The only strange thing I've seen about either of these is that whenever I run a command about installing or upgrading anything with NPM, at some point it always outputs `npm is set to manually installed`. I also have my snapcraft.yaml file attached [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0JkBEM2P-kgLUxvaVR5bGl6MEE), should you wish to see it.